# How to add folder for new projects in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, project, prism

In my solution, I want to add a folder to which I want to add new projects.  What is the procedure for doing this?

I tried to create the folder from within Visual Studio, but it created a 'solution folder'.  I have now researched this and found it is an organisational cue, but only a virtual one, and a 'solution folder' is not reflected in the file system.

I then created a directory in Windows explorer, and found that you could click a button in the Solution Explorer window that shows all files.  I right-clicked on this and selected Include in Project, making it visible, but when I right click on this folder, I don't have 'Add new project' as an option.  Additionally, this folder is part of the main solution project, instead of just being a folder in the solution (if that makes sense).  In any event, I can't drag 'n' drop a project into this folder in Solution Explorer, so that isn't the answer.

Rationale:  I'm trying to work out how to use prism and want to store modules (which are contained in their own VS Projects in the solution) in a 'Modules' directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution folder, as you say, is a virtual thing. You need to create a folder on the file system manually, generally next to your .sln file, and with the same name as the folder you want in Visual Studio. Then add a corresponding solution folder within studio. Right click and add new project on the solution folder, name the new project, then browse it's location to the corresponding folder on the file system, and create the project there.

Comment: You've lost me on the last bit. I add the new project to the solution folder, but in Windows Explorer, I have separate directories for the project and the folder I created and both are at the same level. If I try to copy the project into the folder I created, VS doesn't recognise the project anymore.  I want the project in the directory in both VS and on the filesystem.

Comment: Aye that's right, you've moved the csproj file, so VS doesn't know what to do. Right click the project in VS, remove it, right click the solution folder again and say "Add existing project", find the csproj file and add it. That should sort you out.

Comment: OK, that seems to have worked.  Strikes me as a difficult way of doing something i'd expect to be easy.  Many thanks Greg

Comment: No problem, and yeah it's not exactly intuitive, but not so bad once you've done it a few times.